# Two element subset using c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, subset

I am trying to generate a 2-element subset of all the sets in the code. 
Eg. if the list contains {1,2,3,4}, 2-element subsets will be {1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4}.
I am stuck with the logic and cannot go further. Any help will be appreciated.

```
      class Program
       {
        static List<SortedSet<string>> _items = new List<SortedSet<string>>();
        static SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int i, j, a, b;
        string k;
        Console.WriteLine("\n Enter the number of set to be used: ");
        i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for ( j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>();
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter first element in set {0}:", j);
                k = Console.ReadLine();
                if (k != "stop")
                    set.Add(k);
            } while (k != "stop");
            _items.Add(set);
        }
      }

      public void DisplayTwoElementSets(List<string> set)
        {
            foreach (string item in set)
            {
                GenerateTwoElementSet(setNumber);
            }

        }
        private void GenerateTwoElementSet(int setNumber)
        {
            SortedSet<string> originalSet = _items[setNumber];
            List<SortedSet<string>> twoItemSets = new List<SortedSet<string();
            foreach (string item in originalSet)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this the complete code ? Are we missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the part you are stuck at is the `Console.WriteLine(item);` spot near the bottom of your code.

Your goal is to create a list of unique pair combinations across a range of values. The simplest way is to use two nested for loops, where the inner loop's index value is dependent on the outer loop's index value.

You can store these sets in Lists or Sets, but the type that will probably be the most appropriate would be the Tuple. A Tuple holds exactly the number of values you specify (in this case, 2) and maintains their order in properties with the naming scheme `Item1`, Item2`, Item3`, etc.

(Also note that you are declaring this method within the same class that holds your `Main` method, so for the sake of sanity, it is best to declare this as static.)

```
private static List<Tuple<int, int>> GenerateTwoElementSet(int setNumber)
{
    List<Tuple<int, int>> set = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= setNumber; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= setNumber; j++)
        {
            set.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j));
        }
    }

    return set;
}
```

You can get the values from the set like so:

```
var set = GenerateTwoElementSet(4);
foreach (var tuple in set)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{" + tuple.Item1 + "," + tuple.Item2 +"}");
}

// Outputs the following:
// {1,2}
// {1,3}
// {1,4}
// {2,3}
// {2,4}
// {3,4}
```

**EDIT:** If you want to make pairs out of an existing list rather than a range of numbers, the logic is still the same. You just use the numbers from the above method as indices for your list.

```
private static List<Tuple<string, string>> GenerateTwoElementSetFromList(List<string> list)
{
    List<Tuple<string, string>> set = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
            set.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(list[i], list[j]));
        }
    }

    return set;
}
```

And you use it like so:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>
{
    "apple",
    "pear",
    "orange",
    "plum"
};

var set = GenerateTwoElementSetFromList(list);

foreach (var tuple in set)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{" + tuple.Item1 + "," + tuple.Item2 +"}");
}

// Outputs the following:
// {apple,pear}
// {apple,orange}
// {apple,plum}
// {pear,orange}
// {pear,plum}
// {orange,plum}
```

Comment: This above code is true if I want numbers in my list...What about strings...In this case I am asking from user How many sets they want and what they want inside those sets. And after that i have to generate two element sets and then display two element sets.

Comment: @KinjalMaruShah That would've been good information to include in your question, but see my edit.